# Chrome extensions: storage listener for only one stored variable

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, storage, actionlistener

popup.js:

```
...
chrome.storage.sync.set({'source': source, 'active': active, 'secs': secs, 'domain': domain}, function() {
    console.log('Settings saved');
});
...
```

background.js:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(tab) {
    //something
});
```

So, can I add a listener for changes of (for example) 'active'?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: As you can see in the documentation the listener is invoked for any change.

Comment: It starts the function if I change the value of any stored variable. Thanks wOxxOm

Answer (score 3):

I know this answer is several years old, but this question showed up in my google searches and the current answer is inefficient, since a direct lookup is possible instead of iteration. This code should work better:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
    if ("active" in changes) {
        console.log("Old value: " + changes.active.oldValue);
        console.log("New value: " + changes.active.newValue);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to add an if or switch statement in the listener for specific keys, like so;

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(function(changes, namespace) {
   for(key in changes) {
     if(key === 'active') {
       // Do something here
     }
   }
 });
```